# Different mass load same speed required for vertical conveyor system

Tags: power

this is an imagined though desired requirement for a vertical conveyor system in which a single mass at a time is conveyed vertically, each at the same constant speed of say 1 metre per sec with the only difference being the mass weight of the object being lifted each time. For example a first load of 20 kg is placed onto the belt and conveyed vertically at 1 metre per second, the load is removed from the conveyor belt at the top of the cycle, a second load is added at the bottom weighing 40 kg and it's also conveyed vertically at 1 metre per second then removed at the top of the cycle. The maximum required load will be 60 kg.

Is such an electric motor driven system possible?
If possible, what sort of electric motor and what rating would be recommended for such a system?

If the answer is yes with the qualifier that a large electric motor like a large car engine will perform as required, then what I would like to know is what would be the minimum (with safe margins) rated electric motor, or split the workload with two, that would work as per requirements?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more of a mechanical design question and is better suited on Engineering.SE

Comment: After considering the answers and their application to my scenario I've come to a tentative realisation that it may be variable horsepower I require. I'm going to begin researching variable frequency drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish such a task:

The first is to build a system where a `feedback control loop` monitors a speed sensor, and adjusts the motor to produce more or less effort, to nullify any error between the measured speed and the desired speed.  This may be done with things like a tachometer winding, or optical encoders, and the error amplifier and motor drive may employ either analog or digital techniques.

The other approach is to use a motor technology which has a property of operating at a fixed speed, somewhat independent of load.  An AC `induction motor` is one such technology - essentially, the "preferred" rotation rate is the AC line frequency divided by half the number of poles.  So for example, with a 60 Hz supply (3600 cycles per minute) a 4-pole motor would rotate at 1800 RPM.  However, when performing any useful work, induction motors exhibit a property called "slip" in that their mechanical rotation lags slightly behind the rotation of the electrical fields.  Such a motor usually has a nameplate RPM of 1750 to approximate this.  **However, the degree of slip will increase with increasing load**.

So, if your speed requirement is not too strict, you may be able to use an amply-rated AC induction motor with mechanical belt drive reducing to the desired speed.  However, if your speed requirement is very strict, you probably need a closed loop motor control with loop gains tuned to the dynamics of the system.

Answer (score 1):

60 kg x 1 m/s x 9.80885 = 588 Newton-meters per second = 588 watts. Just to lift the weight, the motor must be able to produce a mechanical power output of 588 watts. In addition, the motor must overcome the friction of the conveyor mechanism and any required gearing. The friction depends on the length and design of the conveyor, the gear ratio and overall design of the mechanical drive train. I would guess that friction could add anywhere between 10% and 50% to the power requirement for a conveyor that does not exceed 6 meters in length. The motor would then need to be rated 0.65 to 0.9 kW. A single phase or 3-phase AC induction motor would probably be the best choice unless there is a need for speed control or some other requirement that has not been mentioned. The motor speed would probably be anywhere between 950 and 1750 RPM.

Using an ordinary induction motor without any electronic speed regulation system, the speed of the conveyor would be about 2% faster with the 20 kg load compared to the 60 kg load.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the good answers already given, a common method for providing a constant speed is to drive the motor with an AC variable frequency drive that can control the motor speed under varying loads. These are commonly available in single and three phase versions.

You will also find some manufacturers in the market that supply an integrated motor and drive. While they offer less flexibility, they greatly simplify the field installation.

Comment: There are not many VFD's with single-phase output, although many will accept single-phase input (for smaller motors). It is fair to say that the OP should get a three phase motor if he wishes to use a VFD.

Comment: @Glenn: Will the induction motor slip on VFD too? All the VFD does is change the motor supply frequency. It doesn't (usually) monitor the motor speed and so does not give closed loop control. If I'm right then running the VFD on 50 or 60 Hz (wherever) will result in increasing slip with increasing load just as it would directly on mains.

Comment: @Transistor Motor's do slip with VFD's. Slip RPM is proportional to motor torque regardless of speed. If, at 60 Hz, a motor slips 50 RPM from 1800 RPM at no load to 1750 RPM at full load, it will slip from from 600 RPM to 550 RPM at 20 Hz. The difference is that the VFD will detect the torque increase and increase the frequency to compensate. Without measuring speed, a VFD can maintain set speed within 0.5%.

Comment: Some VFD's advertise that they employ "sensorless vector control" which apparently allows them to maintain very good control of output set speed. Some are simple V/F.

Comment: The drive senses the slip and adjusts for it. Very common for these types of applications.